# How do I combine my jQuery and set default content if no click

Tags: jquery

It's possible to combine my jQuery below in simple code?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.type").live('click', function () {
        var type = $(this).data("id");
        $('#advertisements').load("ads.php?" + type);
    });
    $("a.maincat").live('click', function () {
        var maincat = $(this).data("id");
        $('#advertisements').load("ads.php?" + maincat);
    });
    $("a.subcat").live('click', function () {
        var subcat = $(this).data("id");
        $('#advertisements').load("ads.php?" + subcat);
    });
    $("a.region").live('click', function () {
        var region = $(this).data("id");
        $('#advertisements').load("ads.php?" + region);
    }); 
    $("a.byuser").live('click', function () {
        var byuser = $(this).data("id");
        $('#advertisements').load("ads.php?" + byuser);
    });     
});
```

and according to this code how do I load default content is by  `$('#advertisements').load("ads.php?" + 1);`

Currently need to click for load a specific content.

Let me know

Comment: You mean how to factorize your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Description

You can use multiple selectors because you always need the data from the `id` attribute
and load everytime from the same script.

#### Sample

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.type,a.maincat,a.subcat,a.region,a.byuser").live('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        $('#advertisements').load("ads.php?" + id);
    });   

    $('#advertisements').load("ads.php?" + 1);
});
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery - Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

## Update

Are you sure that you want `$(this).data("id")` and not the `ìd` value of the element that get clicked ?

If you want the value from the `id` attribute do this

`var id = $(this).attr("id");`

instead of

`var id = $(this).data("id");`

### - [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/WtL9G/)

Comment: Thanks, how about if I want to keep a different `var` because I used `data-id="type=1"`. So on callback `$_GET['type'] = 1` or I'm doing wrong here.. Let me know

Comment: You can do this like your question. My answer is updated. Simple `$('#advertisements').load("ads.php?" + 1);` outside the `live` binding will load your defaults instantly.

Comment: @dknaack thank you so much with an example and information. it's working fine ;)

Comment: **Always just this.id is better than $(this).attr('id'). **

Answer (score 1):

If you can enclose those links in a div/li tag as below then,

```
<div class="links_to_load" >
  <a href="#" id="something1>Something 1</a>
  <a href="#" id="something2>Something 2</a>
  <a href="#" id="something3>Something 3</a>
  <a href="#" id="something4>Something 4</a>
  <a href="#" id="something5>Something 5</a>
</div>
```

and you can bind them all like below,

```
$('.links_to_load > a').live('click', function () {
   //do the stuffs here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can simplify the code by using multiple selectors, and if I understand you correctly, load the default content too:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.type, a.maincat, a.subcat, a.byuser, a.region").live('click', function () {
        $('#advertisements').load("ads.php?" + $(this).data("id"));
    });

    $('#advertisements').load("ads.php?1");
});
```